# Writing a Delphi wrapper for P/Invoke & mscorlib.dll 

Tags: .net, delphi

As I have been reading up

I need to get to some foundation to build safely on
When .net takes up a *.dll from within windows it no longer becomes available to .com.
1/ Does this rule mean I loose loadlibray() and GetProcAddress() to load a .net dll like mscorlib.dll.  one developer says no, So I'm asking what boundaries do I have.
Has delphi installed loadlibray() and GetProcAddress() into delphi code?

2/ MSCorEE.dll has a list of methods for wrapping the mscorlib.dll, That I'm about to create a *.pas file to connect to the MSCorEE.dll. Can I use a mscorlib_tbl file as a reference to the mscorlib.dll.

3/ After installing P/Invoke I have no reference to create a Delphi wrapper.
can some suggest something I could use please.

4/ If I could find a copy of mscoree.h & metahost.h & MSCorEE.dll it would save me a lot of work.

Comment: P/Invoke isn't something you "install." It's the name for a *technique* that .Net programs employ to use non-.Net DLLs. Since it appears you're not writing a .Net program, you don't have to worry about P/Invoke. What *are* you trying to do? Also, why do you keep on creating new accounts for yourself?

Comment: I know what P/Invoke is but no one else seems to be wanting to write a wrapper I'm asking for help.
Can you Decomple P/Invoke into assembly.

Comment: your question is total nonsense

Comment: Looking over your previous questions you seem to be totally and utterly confused about the task you are working on. It seems to be something to do with Delphi and .NET, and I suspect almost all the questions are irrelevant as it is your approach to the task that needs to change. I am convinced you don't need PInvoke, assembler, or any other low-level techniques to achieve your goal, and we could help you if you gave as some idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to achieve something like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/simpleclrhost.aspx

Install the [Microsoft SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowssdk/archive/2010/05/25/released-windows-sdk-for-windows-7-and-net-framework-4.aspx) and you'll get all .h needed files.

Then you can convert the C header file into Delphi. You'll find how in [this article of Rudy's Delphi Corner](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html).

But you'll need a lot of understanding about how the low-level managed code works, to interface with Delphi unmanaged code.

I don't exactly understood what you want to do. Take a look at existing solutions like the one call [COM interop](http://interop.managed-vcl.com/cominterop_delphi.php), instead of sinking into low-level not documented APIs. It may save a lot of time.

More easily, and from my experiment, you can easily call DotNet call from a Delphi application, just by exposing some DotNet objects a COM objects, then call them from Delphi. Even DotNet GUI can be called very easily. You'll just be aware to register the DotNet COM objects for the Wow64 compatibility layer, since Delphi applications are only 32 bit (yet).

Comment: Why did you downvote? Please say what's wrong with this answer. Of course, the question is a bit "obfuscated", but I'm not the one to blame. I just want to help here, by providing links and a bit of feedback from experiment.